# Subtracting two binary in char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, bit

I am a new member of the forum. I am trying to subtract two binary numbers which the bits are stored as char in an array. I have number as an structure:

```
struct number {
    unsigned char *digits; 
    size_t number; 
};
```

And I subtract in another function:

```
void subtractionTwoBinaryNumbers(number &firstNumber, number &secondNumber) {
    for (size_t i = firstNumber.number; i > 0; i--) {
        unsigned char mask = 0b00000001;
        for (int j = CHAR_BIT - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (((mask & firstNumber.digits[i - 1]) > (mask & secondNumber.digits[i - 1])) ||
                ((mask & firstNumber.digits[i - 1]) == (mask & secondNumber.digits[i - 1]))) {
                firstNumber.digits[i - 1] = ((mask & firstNumber.digits[i - 1]) - (mask & secondNumber.digits[i - 1]));

            } else if ((mask & firstNumber.digits[i - 1]) < (mask & secondNumber.digits[i - 1])) {
                firstNumber.digits[i - 1] = ((mask & secondNumber.digits[i - 1]) - (mask & firstNumber.digits[i - 1]));
            }
            mask <<= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm printing the number in another function and it runs correctly.
I would like compute the score in firstNumber.digits. But the score is:

```
first number: 00001111
second number: 00000101
score: 00000000
```

What did I do wrong? Thank you for each answer on my questions!

Comment: Since when is 0b00000001 valid numeric notation?

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` than character arrays.  Character arrays suffer from buffer overrun and their size cannot be easily changed.

Comment: I don't understand.  If you have the value as `number::number`, why not subtract the two `number::number` fields, then convert the result to a textual binary version?

Comment: Off-topic:  Having a member name the same as a structure name is not an ideal programming practice; it can lead to confusion and typos.

Comment: I know that this algorithm subtraction is not completely and not work correctly but I would like store score in char array.

Comment: Thomas Matthews: Thank you advice in practice good programming!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ehm... since c++14

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so... there are many issues with your code, I'll point a few them out:

1. When you subtract `(mask & firstNumber.digits[i - 1]) - (mask & secondNumber.digits[i - 1])` you will always get either `0`, `1` or `-1`. Then you store that value into back into `firstNumber` causing you to lose all of the other bits.
2. As you probably noticed, the above subtraction could return `-1`, which you actually did a `if` statement, probably trying to avoid that, but notice that you did same opertion in the `else` statement; so you are actually storing `-1` back into `firstNumber`. (`-1` sets every bit to `1`, which eventually led to `1 - 1` and stored `0` in the whole thing.

Okay, I'll stop there. In order to help you, I won't fix your code because there are a lot of thing wrong. Instead, I'll propose something else:

To make thing simpler, I'll assume that firstNumber is bigger than secondNumber and to make it unmistakable, I'll also change their names
In this approach, I'll have to check which one is bigger before calling the function and if secondNumber is bigger, you manually signal negative value whenever you print the result of the inverse subtraction (second - first).
To avoid that, you could also use the negative representation of values, as it follows: if the first bit is set, the number is negative; if the number is negative, it's represented as: `~(number - 1)` where `~` is the inverse bitwise operator.

```
struct number {
    unsigned char *digits; 
    size_t length; 
};

// the function returns if biggerNumber is trully bigger than lesserNumber;
// if it returns false, the computed result is wrong (and the original value was lost, you better fix that!)
bool subtractionTwoBinaryNumbers(number* biggerNumber, number* lesserNumber) 
{
    for (size_t i = biggerNumber->length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        if (biggerNumber->digits[i] < lesserNumber->digits[i])
        {
            if (i > 1)
            {
                // I'll carry an unit from the higher digit, in order to do the substraction.
                // as in: 12-9 = 0(12)-0(9) = 0(3)-0(0) = 3
                unsigned char aux = -1; // -1 actually means 0b11111111
                aux -= lesserNumber->digits[i];
                biggerNumber->digits[i] += aux;
                --(biggerNumber->digits[i-1]);  
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            biggerNumber->digits[i] -= lesserNumber->digits[i];
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: using `#define` on a keyword is undefined behaviour. `bool`, `true` and `false` are keywords

Comment: It's true, @M.M, if you think of it as C++. I coded in pure C, that is the reason I did so, once they are not keywords in C; originally the question was tagged with both c and c++; only afterwards edited (check log)

Comment: Sory for of my understatement. This question concern possible pure C not C++.

Comment: Cool, I like it better ! Did my answer solve your problem? If it did, please make sure to set it as answered.

Comment: In  C use `#include <stdbool.h>` to get bools.  `number &biggerNumber` would be an error in C so your answer was never "coded in pure C"

Comment: Now, that is for sure. Didn't even see it, thank you!